# Div go to a new line in susy grid sytem instead being in one single line

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-sass

I want to make a 12 columns page with susy which contain 3 equally spaced centred divs but when I do this

HTML :

```
<div id='container'>
   <div class='col-1'></div>
   <div class='col-2'></div>
   <div class='col-3'></div>
</div>
```

SASS :

```
#container{
   @include container(80%);
   @include layout(12);

   .col-1{ background:red; }
   .col-2{ background:blue; }
   .col-3{ background:green; }

   .col-1,.col-2,.col-3{
       @include span(1 of 3);
       height:100px;
   }
}
```

The 3rd div go to a new line as this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnnYy.png) but I want them in one single line.

And in my CSS file there is :

```
#container .col-1, #container .col-2, #container .col-3 {
   width: 28.57143%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 7.14286%;
   height: 100px;
}
```

**UPDATE:**   If I am right in my calculation 3*28.57143 + 7.14286*3 != 100 , it is approximately 107 , But why ?

> 28.57143 is the width of each div and 7.14286 is the right margin in percentage

Comment: Did you try looking at the compiled CSS to see if it generates what you expected?

Comment: There is a weird thing the css file, maybe I am wrong in the calculation but here is it I am gonna update the question

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution I had to implement the settings for the susy grid system before .

```
  $susy: (
    container: auto,
    columns: 12,
    gutters: .25,
    gutter-position: inside,
    math: fluid,
    output: isolate,
);
```